# save the radiobutton and check

Tags: android, arraylist, radio-button

I need help from any one..

I'm facing difficult in checks the radio button.

My concept is how to save the radio button in arraylist and again how to check the selected value from arraylist. If suppose imagine a quiz app. I have a set of questions and answers in a separate array. I'm displaying it.Its fine. Now if i came to pervious question i should check the selected answer already which has stored in an arraylist. Likewise for next question.  How to implement this? I feel difficult in this.

When 1st question displays i check and get the answer like this..

```
btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {             
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
    String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
```

When i press next button for next question like do like this same and get the answer in a `string` and while i press previous i have used same like that.. but i should not do like that instead i should check already choosen answer..

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks a lot in Advance..

Comment: does your quiz change the order of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
  radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdbGp1);
  radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               @Override public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)            { // TODO Auto-generated method stub for(int i=0; i
                  RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);

                   String text;                   
                 if (btn.isPressed() && btn.isChecked() && questNo < 5)
                  {

                      Log.e("corrAns[questNo]",corrAns[questNo]);

                 if (corrAns[questNo].equals(btn.getText()) && flag==true)
                 {
                 score++;
                 flag=false;
                 checked = true; 
                 }
                 else if(checked==true)
                 {
                 score--;
                 flag=true;
                 checked = false;
                 }



                  }
             } tvScore.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score) + "/5"); Log.e("Score:", Integer.toString(score)); } });
```

this is the snippet you can go ahead and modify according to your need...
i hope this will help
also check this [link](http://maxood-android-corner.blogspot.in/2010/08/developing-quiz-app-on-android.html)

Comment: I have understood the your snippet little. But i can't able to implement..please see my above edit in question..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your implementation, but I would have a class called Question, for example, that would contain the question, the answers in an array, the right answer (just the id of the array) and the selected answer (just the id of the array).

So, in your program you will have a set of Question objects and you will have the option selected and then you can just put `radioButton.toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashMap<RadioGroup,Integer> hashMap` to store the value inside the

```
btn_practicerg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {             
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)group. findViewById(checkedId);
    String temp = radioButton.getText().toString();
    hashMap.put(group,checkedId);
```

later you can retrieve the value of RadioGroup in hashmap just pass the object of RadioGroup to the HashMap as key. eg

```
RadioGroup mOption = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.option);
mOption.check(hashMap.get(mOpiton));
```